# ODP.NET TCP tansport address error connecting to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, powershell, odp.net

I am using OPD.NET managed data provider (version 12C) in PowerShell version 4.0. By using the below code, I am able to successfully run and get the output in a Windows 2012 server where the Oracle DB server instance is locally hosted. So I am able to get the output when I run the code locally on the DB server which is a Windows 2012 server. If I run the same code in another desktop which is Windows 8.1, I am getting the below error:

> Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure

There is no Oracle instant client on WIndows 8.1; only ODP.NET DLL files exists.

Both Windows 8.1 and Windows 2012 has network connectivity and DNS names resolvable.

Windows 2012 is a 64 bit OS and Windows 8.1 is 32 bit OS. I learnt that the ODP.Net does not have dependency on OS architecture.

Code is:

```
Add-Type -Path "D:\ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC12cR4\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

$ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =123.0.0.71)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = AGY));User ID=system;Password=system;Connection Timeout=480;"
$con = New-Object -TypeName Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($ConnectionString)
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText='SELECT * FROM v$version'
try {
    $con.Open()
} catch [System.Exception] {
    Write-Host "Exception caught is = $_"
    break;
}
$rdr=$cmd.ExecuteReader()
if ($rdr.Read()) {
    $rdr.GetString(0)
}

if($con.State -eq "Open") {
    $con.Close() 
}
```

Comment: Did you check that IP address and port (`(HOST = 123.0.0.71)(PORT = 1521)`) are correct, and that you can telnet to that port on that host?

Comment: no telnet from windows 8.1 to DB server .
Connecting To 123.0.0.71...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1521: Connect failed.

Comment: There you have your problem. Check that you have the right IP address and port, that you can reach the host (`traceroute`), that the DB server is accepting connections on the external interface (`netstat`), and that the firewall allows connections to the port.

Comment: Tracert.exe is working fine within 1 hops from windows 8.1 to DB server but telnet is failed. I ran netstat -a on DB server which is hosted on Windows server 2012 and its says that the port 1521 is in listening mode. Is there any other fix to open the telnet communication from windows 8.1 to DB server on Windows 2012 OS? Any other configuration that I need to consider?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I found the root cause. It was a windows domain firewall that got enabled on the DB server on Windows 2012 OS. I turned off and it started to work